# How can I specify the database I want to dump in defaults-file

Tags: mysql

I want do configure a mysqldump command entirely through the defauts-file, but it seems not to be possibly  to specify the database in the file.

I tried

```
databases=mydb
databases mydb

databases="mydb"
databases "mydb"
```

I always get the message

```
mysqldump: ignoring option '--databases' due to invalid value 'mydb'
```

On the commandline I only get this message, when I use the following command:

```
 mysqldump: --databases=mydb
```

Only this works

```
 mysqldump .... --databases mydb
```

works.

Must the databasename passed on the commandline?

Comment: In my case I want to have the database in the config file but still specify tables on the command line, e.g. `mysqldump --defaults-file=config.cnf --skip-comments --skip-tz-utc --tables mytable > "sql/mytable.sql"` - with that i get "access denied to database 'mytable' when selecting database"

Comment: File a "feature request" at bugs.mysql.com

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat, any update/feedback on the answer I posted?

Answer (score 4):

If you run `--help` you get

```
$ mysqldump --help

Usage: mysqldump [OPTIONS] database [tables]
OR     mysqldump [OPTIONS] --databases [OPTIONS] DB1 [DB2 DB3...]
OR     mysqldump [OPTIONS] --all-databases [OPTIONS]

...
databases                         FALSE
...
```

So if you see the `--databases` is a boolean flag, so in the config if you specify just `databases` then it would mean the flag is `TRUE`. Now the database name is always a positional argument and needs to be given at the command itself.

We do some workaround to overcome that by using a bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
database=$(mysqldump --print-defaults | tr ' ' '\n' | awk -F'=' '/databases/ {print $2}')
mysqldump $@ $database
```

What this does is that it prints the default config, which doesn't get validate so you can provide invalid options also. And then extract the database using the same from the config and then pass the command from terminal. Now if I do

```
$  ./mysqldump.sh
Warning: mysqldump: ignoring option '--databases' due to invalid value 'testing'
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.6.40, for Linux (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: testing
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.6.40

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

It works. We can us a different name instead of `databases` as well. But the workaround I should doesn't anyway support multiple databases, but it os not trivial to update it to let it do so

Comment: Thanks, this seems like the best way. Strange that the option cannot be set directly in config.

Answer (score 1):

Can you source it? Something like:

```
source <PATH_TO_DEFAULTS_FILE> && mysqldump -u $user -p $pass $databases ...
```

Comment: This is not a good approach for multiple reasons, mysql config can be split into different files, plus the config has sections also which you can't source, next this would mean specifying every variable in the config, again in the command. Then what is the point of using the config file at all?

Answer (score 1):

After MySQL 5.7+, you can use [mysqlpump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlpump.html). In many cases, it's a drop-in replacement for mysqldump. It allows you to specify `--include-databases` and `--exclude-databases`. You can add these options to your `.cnf` file under the `[mysqlpump]` section:

```
[mysqlpump]
include-databases = "mydb1,mydb2"
```

See [mysqlpump object selection](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqlpump.html#mysqlpump-filtering) docs for more info.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
mysqldump --user='{{USER}}' --password='{{PASSWORD}}' -h {{HOST}} {{DATABASE}} {{TABLE_NAME}} > database.sql
```

Comment: This works, thanks, but ideally I specify the database in the defaults-file.